# Sharepoint integrated report when renders report on aspx page gives error

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, reporting-services

I am trying to render sharepoint integrated report on aspx page. Here is the code:

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(" http://<sharepointServer>/sites/");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "http://<SharepointServer>/sites/<app>/<reportlist>/Reportname.rdl";
```

While getting the parameters I am getting the following error:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.MissingEndpointException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Little late though, but below solution worked for me -

Couple of things to be noted for SharePoint Integrated Mode:

1. The report viewer must be pointed to the report server proxy, which
   sits under a SharePoint site. In other words, instead of setting
   ServerReport.ReportServerUrl to
   "http://{sharepointServer}/sites/{app}", it should be set to
   "http://{sharepointServer}/sites/{app}/_vti_bin/ReportServer".
2. The report path must be the absolute path to the .RDL in SharePoint.
       So, ServerReport.ReportPath should be set to
       "http://{sharepointServer}/sites/{app}/{ReportList}/MyReport.rdl".

   > ```
   > ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://{sharepointServer}/sites/{app}/_vti_bin/ReportServer");
   > ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "http://{sharepointServer}/sites/{app}/{reportlist}/Reportname.rdl";
   > ```